# How store queries Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I'm going to fetch my database twice with different values ​​for Id. But I need to save those two queries somewhere and then send them to the res.render. I already tried to save in array but it returns undefined.

```
app.post('/searchInventory', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
        con.query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%" + req.body.keyword + "%'", function(err, result){
            data = [];
            for(var a = 0; a < result.length; a++){
                console.log(a);
                con.query("SELECT products.id AS id, products.name AS name, products.price AS price, SUM(enter.quantity) AS quantity FROM products JOIN enter ON products.id = enter.id_prod WHERE enter.id_prod = "+mysql.escape(result[a].id)+";", function(err, results, fields){
                // I need to store the query from here
                data =+ results
                });
            }
            console.log(data); //Undefined
            res.render('inventory', {results: results});
        });
    })
```

Comment: Are you sure something is being returned in `result`? I would add a `console.log` to print our `result.length` or the contents of `result`.

Comment: actually return is written in first query while second nested query is run in parallel to the res.render statement. As db queries are async, you won't get any result.

Comment: Yes, I have already given a console.log and it returns the rows

Comment: Confused. Do you need to store queries or results?

Comment: Store results from the queries

Answer (score 1):

The question is around async db query which needs to be taken care.
What first you can do to make it easy and readable is creating a query promise.

```
function dbQueryPromise(query) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(query, (err, results) => {
      if(err) return reject(err);
      resolve(results);
    })
  })
}
```

Now you can use this promise to handle your required behaviour :

```
dbQueryPromise("SELECT id FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%" + req.body.keyword + "%'")
  .then(results => {
   const promiseArray = results.map(result => {
     return dbQueryPromise("SELECT products.id AS id, products.name AS name, products.price AS price, SUM(enter.quantity) AS quantity FROM products JOIN enter ON products.id = enter.id_prod WHERE enter.id_prod = "+mysql.escape(result.id)+";")
   })
   Promise.all(promiseArray).then(allResults => { res.render('inventory', { results: allResults})})
})
```

Comment: It did not give an error, however in the file ejs it does not show anything. I'm putting these results in a table in html. But it shows two blank lines in the table.

Comment: Can you console results before calling res.render?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-query to query the product instead of query twice.

```
con.query("SELECT products.id AS id, products.name AS name, products.price AS price, SUM(enter.quantity) AS quantity FROM products JOIN enter ON products.id = enter.id_prod WHERE enter.id_prod IN ( SELECT id FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%?%') ", req.body.keyword, function( error, result){
    console.log(result)
})
```

also, data += result would not stack the array. You can use Array.prototype.concat to combine two array.

Example:

```
data = data.concat(result)
```

or

```
data = [].concat(data, result)
```